# Are bayesian neural networks suited for text (or document) classification?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, text-classification, bayesian-deep-learning, bayesian-neural-networks

I've tried to do my research on Bayesian neural networks online, but I find most of them are used for **image classification**. This is probably due to the nature of Bayesian neural networks, which may be significantly slower than traditional artificial neural networks, so people don't use them for text (or document) classification. Am I right? Or is there a more specific reason for that?

Are bayesian neural networks suited for text (or document) classification?

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! Where did you read that BNNs are _significantly_ slower than other traditional NNs? Also, slower when? While training, testing, or what? Also, what makes you think that this is the reason why people don't use it for text classification?

Comment: This question was also asked here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/458038/82135.